Performing Cleanup Issue Excel Teams File
We have created a file to collaborate with multiple users on Microsoft Teams to see edits in real time on a manufacturing schedule sheet.
Auto-Save is switched on for this purpose and you can see where other users are in the sheet. However, if you make changes and close the sheet a dialog box appears with the message "Performing Clean up - Excel is uploading your most recent changes. This will take a moment. If you'd rather not wait etc". This dialog box will not disappear and if you cancel or close the box your changes are not visible to another user.
I have tried to turn off auto-save, save changes and turn back on. Clear office upload cache. Reduce size of the file (only 3mb) so don't think this is important.

It looks like it is an issue with the office cache. This worked for me and hopefully for others:

Windows Key and R to open run.
Paste this into the box: %localappdata%\Microsoft\Office\16.0\OfficeFileCache
Delete the folder named "0"
Click on OneDrive in Toolbar should say files are synced.
Re-Open file and test again


I thought you said you attempted to clear the office upload cache? Yet, you are saying when you cleared this cache, the problem did in fact go away?
